# Error aleatorio al recorrer un json en una funcion javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Tengo un error de : data[key].forEach is not a function. pero es totalmente aleatorio, a veces ejecuta perfectamente otras no.

Este es mi codigo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [[5], [5]]
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    $('#button').click( function () {
        var dias=[];
        var mydata = table.row('.selected').data();
        var idpac=mydata[0];
        // VERIFICO EL CHECK DE LOS DIAS A ELEGIR
        if($("#lunes").is(':checked')) {
            dias.push("lunes");
        }
        if($("#martes").is(':checked')) {
            dias.push("martes");
        }
        if($("#miercoles").is(':checked')) {
            dias.push("miércoles");
        }
        if($("#jueves").is(':checked')) {
            dias.push("jueves");
        }
        if($("#viernes").is(':checked')) {
            dias.push("viernes");
        }

         var nsesiones=$("#nsesiones")[0].value;
        var diag=$("#diagnosticoSelect")[0].value;


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'turno/calculo',
            data:{data:JSON.stringify(dias),nsesiones:nsesiones,idpac:idpac},
            success: function(response) {
              createSelects(response,idpac,diag);

            }
            });

    } );







    function createSelects(data,idpac,diag) {
        var i=1;
        var f = document.createElement("form");
        f.setAttribute('method',"post");
        f.setAttribute('action',"turno/confirmar");
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(f);

        data=JSON.parse(data);
        for(let key in data) {
            var wrapper = createWrapper();
            var input = createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('name',"dia"+i);
            input.setAttribute('readOnly',true);
            var select = createElement('select');
            select.setAttribute('name',"horario"+i);

            input.value = key;
            data[key].forEach(function(hour) {
                var option = createElement('option');
                option.setAttribute('value', hour);
                option.textContent = hour;
                select.appendChild(option);
            });
            wrapper.appendChild(input);
            wrapper.appendChild(select);
            f.appendChild(wrapper);

            i++;
        }
        var input1 = document.createElement("input");

        input1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

        input1.setAttribute("name", "Cantidad");
        input1.setAttribute("value", i-1);
        f.appendChild(input1);
        var input2 = document.createElement("input");
        input2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input2.setAttribute("name", "paciente");
        input2.setAttribute("value",idpac );
        f.appendChild(input2);
        var input3 = document.createElement("input");
        input3.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input3.setAttribute("name", "diag");
        input3.setAttribute("value",diag );
        f.appendChild(input3);
        var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
        s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
        s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");
        f.appendChild(s);


    }

    function createWrapper() {
        var section = createElement('section');
        section.classList.add('input-group');
        return section;
    }

    function createElement(tagName) {
        return document.createElement(tagName);
    }


});
```

y en /calculo tengo :

```
public function calculo()
{

    $config = $this->configuracion_model->ver();
    foreach ($config as $row) {
        $franjaConfig = $row->franja;
        $consult = $row->cantidad_consultorios;
    }
    $franja1 = ["08:00:00", "08:30:00", "09:00:00", "09:30:00", "10:00:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00"];
    $franja2 = ["12:00:00", "12:30:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00", "14:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:00:00", "15:30:00"];
    $franja3 = ["16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00"];
    switch ($franjaConfig) {
        case 123:
            $franja = array_merge($franja1, $franja2, $franja3);
            break;
        case 12:
            $franja = array_merge($franja1, $franja2);
            break;
        case 13:
            $franja = array_merge($franja1, $franja3);
            break;
        case 23:
            $franja = array_merge($franja2, $franja3);
            break;
        case 1:
            $franja = $franja1;
            break;
        case 2:
            $franja = $franja2;
            break;
        case 3:
            $franja = $franja3;
            break;
    }
    $franjaTotal = array();
    foreach ($franja as $value) {
        for ($i = 1; $consult >= $i; $i++) {
            array_push($franjaTotal, ($value ."-". $i));
        }

    }
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    $nsesiones = json_decode($_POST['nsesiones'], true);
    $paciente = $_POST['idpac'];

    $i = 0;
    $j = 1;
    $franjaPivot = $franja;
    $response = array();
    $franjaObtenidaBD = array();


    while ($nsesiones > $i) {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
        setlocale(LC_TIME, '');
        //PRIMERO CONTROLO QUE EL DIA A BUSCAR ESTE EN EL ARRAY DEL LISTADO DE DIAS POSIBLES
        if (in_array(utf8_encode(strftime("%A", strtotime("+" . $j . "days"))), $data)) {
            $resultadoExistePac = $this->turno_model->existePaciente(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $j . "days")), $paciente);
            $listaHorarioTurno = $this->turno_model->listadoTurnos(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $j . "days")));
            $dia = (date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $j . "days")))."/".utf8_encode(strftime("%A", strtotime("+" . $j . "days")));
            // PREGUNTO SI HAY TURNOS LIBRES
            if ($listaHorarioTurno != 0 and $listaHorarioTurno != 1) {
                // EN ESTE CASO HAY ALGUNOS TURNOS LIBRES
                //Pregunto si el paciente ya tiene turnos
                if ($resultadoExistePac == 0) {
                    //Si no tiene turnos
                    //Entonces saco del array los horarios que hay cargados en la base, en uso. y creo un array con el que asocio los dias
                    //y los posibles horarios para elegir
                        foreach ($listaHorarioTurno as $row) {
                            $horario = $row->desde;
                                 for ($i = 1; $consult >= $i; $i++) {
                                    array_push($franjaObtenidaBD, ($horario ."-". $i));
                                    }
                        }
                    $resultado = array_diff($franjaTotal, $franjaObtenidaBD);
                    $response[$dia] = $resultado;
                 }
                //termina el if de paciente no tiene turno

            } elseif ($listaHorarioTurno == 0) {
                //muestro la franja entera por q esta to-do libre
                $response[$dia] = $franjaTotal;
                $i++;
            }

        }
        $j++;

    }
    $respues=json_encode($response);

}
```

Si alguien me puede dar una mano,desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar uno de los json con los que te han saltado el error?

Comment: {"2016-10-31\/lunes":{"0":"08:00:00-1","1":"08:00:00-2","2":"08:30:00-1","3":"08:30:00-2","4":"09:00:00-1","5":"09:00:00-2"......"}, ... y así continua con distintas fechas.

Comment: Por ejemplo, ahora esta funcionando, creo que el problema esta en que me esta pasando el día miércoles, y el problema esta en el acento "},"2016-11-02\/mi\u00e9rcoles":{"2":"08:30:00-1","3":"08:30:00-2","4":"09:00:00-1","5":"09:00:00-2","6":"09:30:00-1","7":"09:30:00-2"   

Pero no siempre lo pasa así

Comment: Esta es la manera en que genero los dias,  (date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $j . "days")))."/".utf8_encode(strftime("%A", strtotime("+" . $j . "days")));

Donde tendría que usar decodificar?

Comment: En estos momentos, los input con la fecha y el día miércoles los esta creando sin ningún problema, y el response de ajax sigue siendo el día miércoles en el formato raro, osea que ese no es el problema.

Comment: cuando conviertes tu array a json agregale la bandera JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE.... json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: Aparentemente, estaría corriendo perfectamente. Podrías responder a la pregunta, así la selecciono como la respuesta correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo viste en los comentarios, el problema está en el backend, al codificarlo al devolver tu json se solventa tu problema al agregar la bandera [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php).

```
json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

La data (*string*) que estás *parseando* en

`data=JSON.parse(data);`

contiene elementos (que referencias mediante la clave `key` en `data[key]`) que no poseen la propiedad `forEach`

Si quieres evitar que la ejecución de tu bloque de código termine de repente, puedes trabajar previamente en que todos los elementos del objeto `data` para que posean la propiedad `forEach` (dependerá de la lógica de tu algoritmo), o hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
    try{
        data[key].forEach(function(hour) {
            var option = createElement('option');
            option.setAttribute('value', hour);
            option.textContent = hour;
            select.appendChild(option);
        });
    }catch(e){
        //maneja el error aqui
    }
```

Como lo que estás parseando es una respuesta del servidor, deberías entonces revisar también la lógica del algoritmo del *backend* que responde a esa petición AJAX.

Comment: Edité la pregunta, con el código php.